# How to send a DICOM file to PACS using MergeCom toolkit

Tags: c++, dicom

I had a requirement to send the DICOM files created to the PACS using MergeCom tool kit C++. Can anybody post sample code to read the DICOM file from local and send the same to PACS using MergeCom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merge toolkit ships with sample code which is contained in the folder mc3apps. What you are searching for is (in DICOM terms) a C-STORE SCU, and the file with the sample code is stor_scu.c. A brief documentation can be found [here](http://www.merge.com/MergeHealthcare/media/documents/UserManuals/DICOM-Sample-4-6.pdf). I would post the code but it is very long and copyrighted by Merge. But if you have a legal copy of the toolkit you should be able to find it easily.

Comment: I was able to get the code and I understood how to send 1 dicom file. But I had a doubt. If I wanted to send 2 Dicom files, I need to open 1 Association and send the 2 files separately. Right ? i.e. Open 1 association, read the first DICOM file, set the service command, add affected SOP instance UID and affected SOP class UID and send the request. Follow the same for second DICOM file and at the end, close the association. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: No. There is no need to open individual associations for each file. However it depends on the Presentation Contexts you are negotiating. If they are appropriate for all the files you want to send (e.g. All files are CT images), you are fine. If you want to send different SOP Classes in one association, this is also possible. However it is not explained in a few words. Recommended reading: http://www.course-as.ru/download/pdf/DICOM/CookBook.pdf